# WCF DataContracts

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontract, serialization

I have a WCF service hosted for internal clients - we have control of all the clients.  We will therefore be using a data contracts library to negate the need for proxy generation.  I would like to use some readonly properties and have some datacontracts without default constructors.
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Readonly properties are fine as long as you mark the (non-readonly) field as the [DataMember], not the property. Unlike XmlSerializer, IIRC DataContractSerializer doesn't use the default ctor - it uses a separate reflection mechanism to create uninitialized instances. Except on mono's "[Olive](http://www.mono-project.com/Olive)" (WCF port), where it *does* use the default ctor (at the moment, or at some point in the recent past).

Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Name="Bar")]
    private string bar;

    public string Bar { get { return bar; } }

    public Foo(string bar) { this.bar = bar; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Foo orig = new Foo("abc");
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, orig);
        ms.Position = 0;
        Foo clone = (Foo)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I couldn't find any documentation on that and thought I had read that a default constructor was needed.  This works great! Thanks...

Comment: this is fine if you have a simple backing property but what if the readonly property is something like 
public string FooBar { get {return Foo + ' ' + Bar; }} 
how does the datacontract serializer handle that situaion?

Comment: @lomaxx, well, unless you mark it `[DataMember]`, it will do nothing; but that is a read-only property, so I expect it will either ignore you or throw an exception. If you have a getter and setter, it will do whatever your code asks it to do.

Comment: FYI, DataContractSerializer has a SerializeReadOnlyTypes 
setting (starting with framework 4.5) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes.aspx