# Why do I have to implement set-method on properties?

Tags: c#, wcf, properties, set

I noticed that the following code:

```
public Stringification { get { ":)"; } }
```

doesn't expose the property when creating an auto-generated client for WCF communication. However, if I explicitly add the *set* method as follows:

```
public Stringification { get { return SomeProperty + "!"; } set { } }
```

it works dandy. Is it a limitation of WCF? Is it documented anywhere? I couldn't find any info on that...

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation of WCF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2323289/1714342, here's explained

Comment: Someone please answer to get the reputation, or I'll assume that the question should be closed/deleted.   :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172681/wcf-datacontracts Already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of WCF. It needs the set for the deserialization hence the set should be implemented for the get to work.